# XCode / iOS: Iterating through all instances of a given class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, object, loops

I am working on a 3d game engine for the iPhone and Im currently working out how Im going to be handling all of my 3D objects. I have a class that holds information pertaining to each 3D object such as vertexdata, texture information, etc.

I also have a method that is called once every x milleseconds that handles rendering the 3d scene.

Inside of this method, I would like to loop through all of my 3D objects to get access to their render data.

I realize I could store pointers to all of my 3D objects in an array and iterate through this array, but before venturing down this possibly unnecessary road I was wondering if there was away to simply iterate through all instances of a given class (ie my 3d object class), as this would solve my problem.

Pseduo:

For (obj in AEobject3D){

render obj

}

Is something like this possible? If so please excuse the ignorance, I cant seem to find information in the docs / internet, and Im still learning my way through Objective C.

Thanks,
- Adam Eisfeld

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no built-in way to do this. If you wanted to implement it yourself, you'd still have to use an array to keep track of the objects. So I suggest you just use an array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array and be some with it. For instance, UIKit uses the concept of subviews too, which are arrays in arrays.