# Swift/XCode Edit all instances of a Class or UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a custom class of UIButton in Swift and need to find a way to edit all instances of it when any of the buttons are clicked. [I read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968523/xcode-ios-iterating-through-all-instances-of-a-given-class), however that was 5 years ago and was wondering if it is now possible.
I need to do this to make all the other buttons of the class disappear when one of them is clicked and the selected one would change it's color, but then go back to its previous state. And also based on a property value of the class, `itTrue: String = ""` to change the colour, so if `itTrue` was not changed, it would remain it's original color, it `itTrue` was yes, it would change to green, if `itTrue` was no, it would change to pink

I also tried creating an array of the buttons, but that kept giving me errors, and it also looks like it would require a large rewrite of code as the buttons are currently created in a for loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what exactly you intend to do with the buttons and how they would eventually regain visibility but you can add a function to your custom UIButton class to find all other instances on the view that contains one of them (e.g. the one that was pressed).

```
class ExclusiveButton:UIButton
{

    func otherInstances(var onView:UIView? = nil ) -> [ExclusiveButton]
    {
       var result:[ExclusiveButton] = []

       if onView == nil
       {
          onView = superview
          while onView!.superview != nil { onView = onView!.superview }
       }

       for subView in onView!.subviews
       {
          if let button = subView as? ExclusiveButton
             where button !== self
          { result.append(button) }
          else
          { result = result + otherInstances(subView) }
       }

       return result       
    }    
}
```

You can then use button.otherInstances() to iterate through the other instance and make any changes you like.

note: you don't need to specify the view when calling .otherInstances(), the method only needs the parameter internally.

This could also be used internally by your class to encapsulate the behaviour in the class itself rather than push it to the calling code.